# my status bar in android 4.2.2 emulator is broken

Tags: android, android-emulator, statusbar, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Today I found the status bar in android 4.2.2 emulator is broken.I cannot pull it down.
I have no idea what happened.

Comment: have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Yes,I tried many times.(in ubuntu)

Comment: Did you try to wipe the data for the emulator? Is your project showing a notification? Are you using any custom views for the notification?

Comment: "wipe user data" is helpless.I just create a common notification.

Comment: same just happened to me, but it works again after closing, wiping data and starting the emulator. It only happens if I pull the status bar but it doesn't reach the bottom. It bounces back to the top and then I can't drag it.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, as per [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291699/android-emulator-only-opens-notification-bar-once), it seems like it might be a [bug in android](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57129). No response from Google as of the writing of this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a little app wich pulls it down:

```
    StatusBarManager statusBar = (StatusBarManager) getSystemService(STATUS_BAR_SERVICE);
statusBar.expand();
```

Permission is required in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

Comment: Maybe reïnstall the sdk?

Comment: make a new emulator?? delete the whole AVD folder