# Android Emulator only opens notification bar once

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-notification-bar

I'm seeing this strange behaviour. I can only open the notification bar once on the emulator.

Running API level 17 with a 480x800 screen (Nexus One with API level 17 settings) on a Macbook pro / OSX 10.8

Anyone experienced anything similar?

Same as [my status bar in android 4.2.2 emulator is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484062/my-status-bar-in-android-4-2-2-emulator-is-broken)

Bug reported as [Notification bar unusable in 4.2 emulator](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57129)

Comment: Seems to only affect API 17...

Comment: possible duplicate of [my status bar in android 4.2.2 emulator is broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484062/my-status-bar-in-android-4-2-2-emulator-is-broken)

Comment: This question is unclear. Why don't you try to elaborate more on your issue if you really want it solved?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wouldn't use the emulators that come with Eclipse. Use genymotion, its super fast and you can emulate a big range of different devices like the moto x, xperia z, nexus 5 etc. Works like a charm! get it [here](http://www.genymotion.com/)